# asp.net validator that allows everything but not numbers

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

As I put in the title I need a validator (regular expresion, customvalidator, etc) that allows the user to input everything (lettrs, special characters, spaces) but not numbers.

Valid string would be "D'Elia" or "Del Riego" Not Valid String would be " " or "p1" or "1" So I have to allow all letters, all special characters including space, no numbers, and not spaces at the beginning (well, al least that the field doesn't allow that only one space and nothing more can be written)

How can I do that?

Thank you,
Sabrina

Comment: Have you tried `^[^0-9]+$`

Comment: For future reference, there are plenty of .NET-specific online regex testers, such as this one - http://regexhero.net/ - very useful.

Comment: Thanks ! this worked, the only problem now is that it allows that the user inputs only one space, Is there a away to control that at least it has a letters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a positive lookahead at the start to check for atleast one letter.

```
^(?=.*?[A-Za-z])[^0-9]+$
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it but it's still allowing that the user inserts only one space. Is there a way to check at least one letter at the beginning?

Comment: atleast one letter at the begining? try `^[A-Za-z][^0-9]*$` . if the ssue is not solved then update your question with valid and invalid strings.

Comment: is still not working. Valid string would be "D'Elia" or "Del Riego" Not Valid String would be " " or "p1" or "1" 
So I have to allow all letters, all special characters including space, no numbers, and not spaces at the beginning (well, al least that the field doesn't allow that only one space and nothing more can be written)

Thank you!

Comment: add the above comment to your question.

Comment: see my regex works here https://regex101.com/r/uN4lT5/4 or `^(?m)[A-Za-z][^0-9\n]*$` https://regex101.com/r/uN4lT5/5

Comment: It so rare, I saw what you send me and seems to work there, but in my aspx page it still allowing only space option. I don't know what to do

Comment: it's not the problem with regex.